# getRecordNotifyChange is not working all the time

Tags: lightning-web-components, platform-event, get-record-notify-change

Whenever changes happened in child record i want to update a field in my Parent.Parent field should be updated without refreshing the UI. So i have created a trigger in my child ,updated my parent field and captured the parent id. For each parent id I have subscribed my platform event below.

```
    List<Account> lstAccount = new List<Account>();
    List<Platformrefresh__e> eveList =new List<Platformrefresh__e>();
    for (Contact con : lstContact){
        //my logic to update account field
        lstAccount.add(acc);
        Platformrefresh__e event = new Platformrefresh__e();
        event.recordId__c= con.AccountId
        eveList.add(event);
    }
    update lstAccount;
    EventBus.publish(eveList);
```

I have created LWC component and added in my Parent record lightning page. Whenever the change happened in parent i am displaying some message like below

```
handleResponse(response) {
    console.log('entering response'+JSON.stringify(response));
    let parentRecord = response?.data?.payload?.recordId__c;
    if (parentRecord === this.recordId) {
        console.log('entering refresh');
        getRecordNotifyChange([{ recordId: this.recordId }]);
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success',
                message: 'Account updated',
                variant: 'success'
            })
        );
        //Unsubscribe immediately after single refresh.  
        //Makes sure that we're not oversubscribed as disconnectedCallback does not seem consistent.
        //this.unsubscribeToMessageChannel();
    }
}
```

I am getting the message but the value in the UI is not refreshed all the time. Sometimes the UI gets refreshed and sometimes not. Can anyone please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to try putting `getRecordNotifyChange` after `dispatchEvent`, it works for me